# Can't connect to standalone mongodb: No candidate servers found

Tags: php, mongodb

I have debian dev server with stock mongodb; php 5.4 and pecl mongodb drivers v1.4.3.
I tried to create simple conntection using PHP Cli and got exception:

```
php -r "MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::ALL); MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::ALL); new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', array());"
```

the output below:

```
PHP Notice:  PARSE   INFO: Parsing mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  PARSE   INFO: - Found node: 127.0.0.1:27017 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  PARSE   INFO: - Connection type: STANDALONE in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a STANDALONE connection in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: connection_create: creating new connection for 127.0.0.1:27017 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: stream_connect: Not establishing SSL for 127.0.0.1:27017 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: get_server_flags: start in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: send_packet: read from header: 36 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: send_packet: data_size: 73 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: get_server_flags: can't find maxBsonObjectSize, defaulting to 4194304 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: get_server_flags: can't find maxMessageSizeBytes, defaulting to 8388608 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: get_server_flags: found server type: UNKNOWN? in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: is_ping: pinging 127.0.0.1:27017;-;.;29554 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: send_packet: read from header: 36 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: send_packet: data_size: 69 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  CON     INFO: is_ping: last pinged at 1376577544; time: 0ms in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: finding candidate servers in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: - all servers in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: adding connections: in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: filter_connections: done in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: limiting by seeded/discovered servers in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: limiting by seeded/discovered servers: done in Command line code on line 1
PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: limiting by credentials in Command line code on line 1
    PHP Notice:  REPLSET FINE: limiting by credentials: done in Command line code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'No candidate servers found' in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 Command line code(1): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://127.0...', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1
```

I have found workaround - is downgrade dirver version to 1.3.6; but it is not a solution.

Comment: have you tried without mongodb:// so only connecto 127.0.0.1:27017 ?

Comment: yes, the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I solved my problem after installing 10-gen version mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem today, downgraded to the 1.3.6 version of mongo driver in pecl "worked" for me... System: Debian Squeeze
This does the job for you:

```
pecl uninstall mongo
pecl install mongo-1.3.6
```

Comment: As I found out now downgrading to version 1.3.6 only took me past the first error. There are still errors after collections have been created, see https://code.google.com/p/rock-php/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=212.